# WordPress crashing on PHP 7 IIS Server

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, php-7

I have an IIS 7 server setup with numerous domains. I'm testing PHP 7 on one of the domains. It works perfectly and the speed of this version is amazing. However, it tends to crash usually after half an hour or after a couple of hours showing the following browser error:

```
URL is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I have enabled PHP errors logging and manage to pinpoint the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/wp-
admin/includes/class-wp-site-icon.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in 
\wp-admin\includes\admin.php on line 74
```

No idea what I can do here as it is a file within Wordpress.

Comment: There is also the error -  [16-Jan-2018 09:48:11 UTC] Bad CTA Impression Object

Comment: Are you sure the given wordpress code is up to date with php7 ?